# Python: Use reduce to alternate addition and multiplication

Tags: python, reduce

Using only reduce (so no importing anything), how do I write a one-line function to get the following result? It alternates between adding and multiplying elements in a list.

Everything needs to fit in reduce()

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

((1 + 2) * 3 + 4) * 5 + 6 = 71
```

Comment: Do you mean addition and multiplication?

Comment: Just where do those programming restrictions arise?  If this is a homework problem, you must label it as such.

Comment: There are many, inevitably silly, ways to do this with `reduce`.

Comment: I'm trying to learn more about map, filter, reduce and found some example questions. I've just been banging my head against the wall. No grades are involved. Scouts honor.

Comment: Yeah, then why "no importing anything?" The use-case for `reduce` is when you have a single operation that applies to two values of a given type and returns a value of that type. You can hack something, but it won't be pretty, and it really makes no sense to use reduce here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
print(reduce(lambda a, b: a[1] + b[1] if isinstance(a,tuple) 
           else a + b[1] if b[0] % 2 else a * b[1], enumerate(numbers)))
```

---

Breakdown:

```
print( reduce(lambda a, b: a[1] + b[1] if isinstance(a, tuple) 
                           else a + b[1] if b[0] % 2 
                           else a * b[1], 
              enumerate(numbers)
             )
)
```

Comment: I'm trying to better understand both reduce and lambda operations. I saw some example problems, but got really stuck on this one. This is great, and I'll check it off once time allows

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain a cleaner solution using something like this:

```
def myCycle(x, y):
    while True:
        yield from (x, y)  # replace with yield x; yield y for python < 3.3

print (reduce(lambda x, y: (y[0], x[0](x[1], y[1])), 
                  zip(myCycle(int.__add__, int.__mul__), numbers))[-1])
71
```

`myCycle` here is a standin for `itertools.cycle`, which cycles through elements repeatedly.

Comment: I concur that this is much cleaner than my solution so +1 ... however he pretty clearly states no imports ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I'm so sorry, I did not see that. You have my vote too.

Comment: You *could* create your own cycle, something like `def c(): while True: yield add; yield mul`